# Drupal 7 Persmission per custom field

Tags: drupal-7, content-management-system, drupal-modules

Lets say I have content types of *Department*  and *Proposal*. A *Proposal* is submitted from each *Department* users. There is also User(built-in Drupal user entity) with Super Admin and Authors(Roles).

> ***Department***: Id, Name
>
> **Proposal**: Name, file, ***Department*** (node Reference)
>
> **User**: Name, email, Role(Super Admin, Author), ***Department*** (node Reference)

1. I want to enable an Author user to only add a proposal with in their respective Department, meaning Author A in Department X could only publish proposals for Department X.
2. Authors can only view/edit (in the admin page) proposal of their department. This can be achieved by only permitting them to only view own content in the Permission page. But I would like to enable Super Admin to create proposal for a given department and only the relevant Authors can see it.
3. On the front end, all proposals will be publicly available to all user and anonymous user can view it. I only want to force this on the admin page while creating and managing contents.

How do enforce users to follow this workflow by only letting them list proposal only in their departments and add new new proposal?

Comment: Edit the question at the bottom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Implements hook_permission for various actions .
- Assign the permission to the user roles from : yoursite/admin/people/permissions
- Also you can define access callback functions.